# Select query with condition for the column from the second table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 tables (THour_IN and THour_OUT) that have identical schemas:
Columns for THour_IN: Name|date|HourIN
Colums for THour_OUT: Name|date|HourOUT
I make query:

```
SELECT THour_IN.Name, THour_IN.date, THour_IN.HourIN, THour_OUT.HourOUT FROM THour_IN LEFT JOIN THour_OUT ON (Hour_IN.Name = THour_OUT.Name) AND (Hour_IN.date = THour_OUT.date);
```

But this is not correct in my case, because I have multiple rows wtih the same date in the tables. The result is:

```
Name   date       HourIN    HourOUT
AAA 24/11/2013  17:33:06    20:33:27
AAA 24/11/2013  17:33:06    16:36:06
AAA 24/11/2013  07:33:27    20:33:27
AAA 24/11/2013  07:33:27    16:36:06
BBB 18/11/2013              16:36:06
BBB 19/11/2013  07:33:30    
BBB 21/11/2013  07:29:24    08:33:22
BBB 22/11/2013  07:33:30    16:34:53
```

It should be for date 24/11/2013 First HourIN(07:33:27) with Fisrt HourOUT (16:36:06), Second HourIN (17:33:06) with Second HourOUT (20:33:06) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Build segments, then intersect segments.

```
SELECT
  P1.Name, P1.date, P1.HourIN, P1.HourOUT
FROM (
  SELECT
    I.Name, I.date, I.HourIN, O.HourOUT
  FROM
    THour_IN AS I
    LEFT JOIN THour_OUT AS O
      ON (I.Name = O.Name) AND (I.date = O.date)
        AND I.HourIN < H.HourOUT
) AS P1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    I.Name, I.date, I.HourIN, O.HourOUT
  FROM
    THour_IN AS I
    LEFT JOIN THour_OUT AS O
      ON (I.Name = O.Name) AND (I.date = O.date)
        AND I.HourIN < H.HourOUT
) AS P2
  ON P1.name = P2.name AND P1.date = P2.date
    AND P1.HourIN <> P2.HourIN and P1.HourOUT <> P2.HourOUT
    AND P1.HourOUT > P2.HourIN
    AND (P1.HourIN = P2.HourIN AND P1.HourOUT < P2.HourOUT
          OR P1.HourIN > P2.HourIN AND P1.HourOUT = P2.HourOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so:

```
SELECT
  t.Name, 
  t.Date, 
  t.HourIN, (
     SELECT Top 1 HourOut 
     FROM THourOUT o 
     WHERE o.Name=t.Name AND o.Date=t.date And o.HourOUT>t.HourIN 
     ORDER BY o.HourOUT,o.ID ) AS HrOut
FROM THourIN AS t
ORDER BY t.Date, t.HourIN;
```

Note that I have added an ID to the OUT table to ensure that top 1 does not return duplicates.

Here is an example of inserting missing values. It depends on a Numbers table containing integers from 0 or 1 to the highest number of missing values. A number table is useful in many ways.

```
INSERT INTO thourin
            (name,
             [date])
SELECT q.name,
       q.DATE
FROM   (SELECT Outs.name,
               Outs.DATE,
               Outs.countofout,
               Ins.countofin
        FROM   (SELECT o.name,
                       o.DATE,
                       Count(o.name) AS CountOfOut
                FROM   thourout o
                GROUP  BY o.name,
                          o.DATE) AS Outs
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.name,
                                 t.DATE,
                                 Count(t.name) AS CountOfIn
                          FROM   thourin t
                          GROUP  BY t.name,
                                    t.DATE) AS Ins
                      ON ( Outs.name = Ins.name )
                         AND ( Outs.DATE = Ins.DATE )
        WHERE  (( ( Ins.countofin ) <> [countofout]
                   OR ( Ins.countofin ) IS NULL ))) AS q,
       numbers AS n
WHERE  (( ( n.counter ) > 0
          AND ( n.counter ) <= [countofout] - [countofin] ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use this query. Now I have other problem. When I have data such as
Name   date       HourIN
AAA 24/11/2012  07:30:00   
AAA 24/11/2012  15:30:00
AAA 25/11/2012  07:33:27  


Name   date       HourOUT  
AAA 24/11/2012  16:30:00
AAA 25/11/2012  16:00:00  
AAA 25/11/2012  20:00:00 
For technical reasons there are not data for some "in" and "out", they must be 00:00:00
I get result
Name   date       HourIN    HourOUT
AAA 24/11/2012  07:30:00    16:30:00
AAA 24/11/2012  15:30:00    16:30:00
AAA 25/11/2012  07:33:27    20:00:00
How can i add the null values?

Comment: You mean there is a while line missing? No date, no time?

Comment: Do you have a date and name? AAA 24/11/2012 <blank>

Comment: I add entry with blank hour when is only one for a date. I have one entry in IN tbl and two (or more) entries in OUT tbl for the same date, how can I add second (or more) entry in IN table with null Hour?

Comment: INSERT INTO HourIN (Name, Date)
SELECT o.Name, o.Date
FROM HourOUT AS o LEFT JOIN HourIN AS i ON (i.Date=o.Date) AND (i.Name=o.Name) WHERE i.Date IS NULL; I insert record with null TimeIn where I have Time Out for the same date. But the problem is when for the same Date I have two records in TimeOUT and one record In timeIN, how can I add secod record in Timein with null value?  In two tables i have ID_In and ID_Out - Autonumber

Comment: I have added an example, I am not sure what good blank times will be to you.

Comment: you're right! I have added a records with times 00:00:00, but this do'n help :-(

Comment: I suggest you add a flag field to indicate that you have added the time and create an in time one minute before the out time. You can use VBA or do the work manually.

Comment: I add flag, but how can i check who is corresponding record?

Comment: Step through the tables using vba.

Comment: please can you give me a sample or link for something like this. I must read more about VBA.

Comment: Search for the keyword recordset, one example http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners. Note thate you can link on name and date as the inner sql above shows to get missing items.